# Highcharts area fillOpacity do not work when changing the color

Tags: highcharts, opacity

I want an area chart with opacity 0.1. If I do not specify the color, everything works fine:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
}
series: [{
   name: '1',
   data: [1,2,3],
   type: 'area'
}
```

But when I change the color, the opacity is ignored:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
}
series: [{
   name: '2',
   data: [0,1,2],
   type: 'area'
   color: 'red'
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4HkXf/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please use color as hex i.e `"#ff0000"` instead of 'red'.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HkXf/3/

Comment: I had to change from `#333` to `#333333` to make it work. How so very inflexible.

Comment: If anybody needs to convert their colors as well, here is a table with the corresponding values:
https://www.w3schools.com/Colors/colors_names.asp

Answer (score 5):

I resolved it by removing `fillOpacity`, and instead specifying opacity as part of the color using `rbga`:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Buy / Sell ',
    data: data.shares_change,
    type: 'column',
    color: 'rgba(0,128,0,0.4)', // #080
    negativeColor: 'rgba(128,0,0,0.4)', // #800
    pointWidth: 8
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fillOpacity: 0.1,
color: "rgb(0,0,0)"
```

seems to work on all browsers

```
fillOpacity: 0.1,
color: "#000"
```

does not work on all browsers

```
color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
```

does not work on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what the reason is.

but, here is the solution for it

use type in chart level

```
chart:{
type: 'area'
}
```

this will be applied to all the series

here is your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4HkXf/1/

hope this will be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, that partially solve it, but the problem is, that my chart has two series - line and area. The area should have opacity so the line could be seen.

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4HkXf/5/ , I think it solves the problem

Comment: But when you add `color: 'red'` to those two area series, the opacity is lost. Above answer solved it with `color: '#ff0000'`