# fillOpacity and opacity don’t seem to be working

Tags: html, css, image, svg, styling

**Note:** I am well aware of how image masking can solve my problem but I do not wish to opt for it since in that case I will have to use my image as a background and that will cause accessibility issues. Some solution related clip-path is what I'm looking for.

Problem: The `<rect>`s in my SVG aren't responding to changes in `fillOpacity` or `opacity`. The `<rect>`s need to be animated, hence I cannot manipulate the opacity of the entire image/SVG at once. I tried implementing the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792396/19119712) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17021484/19119712) but none of those worked.

This is a react project and the here's the HTML and CSS I'm talking about:

```css
img {
  clip-path: url(#path-One);
  height: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80" alt="Big Data" />
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 673.000000">
    <clipPath id="path-One" transform="scale(1.127, 1.127)">
      <!-- Line 1: -->
      <rect width="10vw" height="10vw" fillOpacity="0" />
      <rect x="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="40vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="50vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="60vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="70vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="80vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <!-- Line 2: -->
      <rect y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="10vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="20vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="30vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="40vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="50vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="60vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="70vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="80vw" y="10vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <!-- Line 3: -->
      <rect y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="10vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="20vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="30vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="40vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="50vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="60vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="70vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="80vw" y="20vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <!-- Line 4: -->
      <rect y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="10vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="20vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="30vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="40vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="50vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="60vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="70vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
      <rect x="80vw" y="30vw" width="10vw" height="10vw" />
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Code in the question itself please. And a `<clipPath>` isn't filled. maybe you wanted a `<mask>`?

Comment: You can put your code IN your question by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I am aware of masks but like I mentioned, using background image will cause accessibility issues. But thanks anyway, cause I wasn't aware <clipPath> isn't filled. Also, the code would've taken up a lot of space here and I've observed people tend to ignore such questions generally. In any case, please take a look at the code in the link if you haven't already.

Comment: Alright, I've added the code.

Comment: The clip path represents a "silhouette of the graphics associated with that element" [CSS Masking Module Level 1 - ClipPathElement](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking/#ClipPathElement), so the opacity attribute will have no effect. Can you explain what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Sure. What I'm trying to do is animate the opacity of the image in a specific order along the `<rect>`s as a user scrolls through my component. I don't wish to use masks as in that case I will have to opt for background image and screen readers ignore background images.

Comment: You don't have an x or y coordinate in your rect with fill opacity. Is it provided by CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing several problems:

### Fill colors and transparency

Your mask elements are **all black** so they will make the masked image **100% transparent**.
Changing the `fill-opacity` from 1 to 0 wont't have an effect – you need to **apply a white fill color** to your `<rect>` elements.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Works</h3>
<svg width="220" height="100" viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <mask id="path-One">
            <g fill="#fff">
            <rect width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="20" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />

            <rect y="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
              </g>
          </mask>
          <image width="100%" mask="url(#path-One)" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80"></image>
        </svg>

<h3>Doesn't work</h3>

<svg width="220" height="100" viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <mask id="path-Two">
            <g >
            <rect width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="20" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />

            <rect y="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

            <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
              </g>
          </mask>
          <image width="100%" mask="url(#path-Two)" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80"></image>
        </svg>
```

### Mask HTML elements with svg masks

Currently, **only Firefox** supports masking of HTML elements with inlined svg masks.

As a workaround you might dynamically convert the svg to a dataURL.

```js
svgToMaskDataUrl( svgMask, imgMasked)

function svgToMaskDataUrl( mask, maskedEl){
  let maskSvg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(mask)
  let dataURL = `data:image/svg+xml,`+ encodeURIComponent(maskSvg);
  maskedEl.style.webkitMaskImage=`url(${dataURL})`;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
img {
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgMask" viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute;">
  <g fill="white">
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

    <rect y="20" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="20" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="20" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="20" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="20" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="20" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

    <rect y="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="40" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="40" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="40" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="40" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="40" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="40" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="40" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="40" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="40" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="40" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />

    <rect y="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="60" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="60" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="60" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="60" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="60" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="60" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="60" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="60" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="60" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="60" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />

    <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="80" x="20" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="80" x="40" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="80" x="60" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="80" x="80" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="80" x="100" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="80" x="120" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="80" x="140" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="80" x="160" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
    <rect y="80" x="180" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="1" />
    <rect y="80" x="200" width="20" height="20" fill-opacity="0" />
  </g>
</svg>

<img id="imgMasked" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80" alt="Your Image" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! Works perfectly! Although, just a minor addition to it, I had to get hold of the elements using `document.getElementBy()` and make the function call from within a useEffect as this is for a React project.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the clip path with a mask. There is no need for setting the image as a background. You can just use the CSS mask property.

```css
img {
  mask: url(#path-One);
  height: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80" alt="Big Data" />
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
    <mask id="path-One" fill="white">
      <!-- Line 1: -->
      <rect id="tile" width="10vw" height="10vw" transform="scale(.99)" />
      <use href="#tile" x="10vw" fill-opacity=".5"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="40vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="50vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="60vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="70vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="80vw"/>
      <!-- Line 2: -->
      <use href="#tile" x="0vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="10vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="20vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="30vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="40vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="50vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="60vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="70vw" y="10vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="80vw" y="10vw"/>
      <!-- Line 3: -->
      <use href="#tile" x="0vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="10vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="20vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="30vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="40vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="50vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="60vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="70vw" y="20vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="80vw" y="20vw"/>
      <!-- Line 4: -->
      <use href="#tile" x="0vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="10vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="20vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="30vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="40vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="50vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="60vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="70vw" y="30vw"/>
      <use href="#tile" x="80vw" y="30vw"/>
    </mask>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but are you sure `fill-opacity` is working in this case? I tried changing its value but nothing happened. Can you please spend some more time and check what the issue might be because I think this may be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @SuryasishPaul I guess it depends on how you plan to change the opacity. In this example it will require some JavaScript.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn’t explain the problem clearly. The problem I'm referring to now is that changing the value of `fill-opacity` between 0 and 1 manually while on the dev server should ideally be rendering the changes in opacity of the image along the `<rect>`s shouldn’t it? Or am I getting something wrong here? In any case, thanks for your time.