# Image not being masked by SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, jsx, vite

The SVG that is meant to mask the image lies under the image and isn’t masking it. Also, adding `WebkitMask` to the inline style makes the image disappear from live server page. I'm using CSS modules, hence the inline styling for the mask (referring to `id`s from CSS modules is a nightmare I want to deal with later). What am I getting wrong here? I checked the other QnAs available but none of those solutions seem to be working. This is a react, SASS and CSS modules project and I need to see the different opacities implemented on the image along the `<rect>`s. The SVG in itself occupies space as intended within the `viewport` just that it isn't masking the image.

Thanks for your time!

```css
img {
    height: 60vw;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80"
          alt="Your Image"
          style={{
            mask: "url(#path-One)",
            WebkitMask: "url(#path-One)",
          }}
        />
        <svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <mask id="path-One">
            {/* Line 1: */}
            <rect width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            {/* Line 2: */}
            <rect y="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="20" x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="20" x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            {/* Line 3: */}
            <rect y="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="40" x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="40" x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            {/* Line 4: */}
            <rect y="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="60" x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="60" x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            {/* Line 5: */}
            <rect y="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
            <rect y="80" x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
            <rect y="80" x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
          </mask>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate ID issues (which you say you want to fix later) can be fixed with a Web Component. Define your SVG **once**, and create those IDs dynamically:

###### Note: **HTML** `<image>` and **SVG** `<image>` are **TWO** *different* technologies.

The HTML `<image>` is very old skool, deprecated, Netscape browser technology.

```css
svg {
  width: 250px;
  background: #efefef
}
```

```html
<svg-avatar r="16" fill="#4267B2" href="//i.imgur.com/iCKbSvQ.png"></svg-avatar>
<svg-avatar r="14" href="//i.imgur.com/zTUDE6c.png"></svg-avatar>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-avatar", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let id     = n => n + Math.random() * 1e18; // create a unique id
      let maskid = id("mask");
      let clipid = id("clip");
      let r      = ~~(this.getAttribute("r") || 14);
      let fill   = this.getAttribute("fill") || "#F6BB43";
      let href   = this.getAttribute("href");
      this.innerHTML = 
      `<svg viewBox="0 0 60 40">
      <defs>
        <mask id="${maskid}">
          <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="40"/>
          <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="${r+2}"/>
        </mask>
        <clipPath id="${clipid}">
          <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="${r}"/>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <circle mask="url(#${maskid})" fill="${fill}" r="${r}" opacity="1" cx="20" cy="20"/>
      <image href="${href}" clip-path="url(#${clipid})" x="21" y="2" width="35" height="35"/>
      </svg>`
}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76789347/19119712 The `<rect>`s need to have a white `fill` for the masked image to be visible. Also, **only Firefox** allows masking HTML elements at the moment. Therefore, the mask had to be implemented using a workaround for it to work on all browsers.